# Download a single invoice vs multiple behavior

Tags: tables, menu, options, download

I have a table which display all of the user's outstanding invoices.

Currently, the user is allowed to select one or multiple invoices that they can either download (PDF format) or pay all at once.

[image]

I would like to add the ability to quickly download a single invoice. They are able to do this currently by just selecting the invoice they want to download and clicking on the download button up top.

I came up with 2 options:

**(A)** Add a download button next to the invoice numbers:

[image]

**(B)** Collapse the `Copy` button AND `Download` button into an ellipsis menu.

I think this is a cleaner approach, but if multiple invoices were selected AND the user opens up one of these ellipsis menus, it might suggested that they are about to download multiple invoices instead of just one?

[image]

Comment: I prefer A. It doesn't make sense to put them in a menu and add the number of clicks when you have enough space.

Answer (score 1):

I see a certain disorder and consequently redundant elements.

First, the elements to act by jumping from left to right alternately are very confusing.

[image: jumping]

Second, the repetition of actions, both for the selected item and for the single item.

---

I would try to find an alternative that unifies everything, for example placing all the action elements on a single column where those of the header act on all the selected ones (the top select icon selects all) and the icons of each item row acts on each element.

[image]